# add to cart not working localhost Only in chrome (Magento 2 fresh install )

Tags: magento2, localhost

I've installed magento 2 fresh on `localhost`, and trying to add items to cart but didn't work..

when click on **add to cart** button, button will change into **adding**
and stays there, didn't add to cart item.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 30):

Change your base URL from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Using `localhost` as the domain in your base URL causes problems in Magento 2.

Magento's base URL configuration is located in the `core_config_data` table. The following `value`s may need to be changed:

- `web/unsecure/base_url`
- `web/secure/base_url`

For example, if you previously had `http://localhost/magento2community/`, you should change it to `http://127.0.0.1/magento2community/`

After changing the url, flush the cache (`bin/magento cache:flush`). You might also need to [clear out your var directories](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html).

Comment: why is the answer written as code?

Comment: This solved my problem on MAMP.

Comment: Working fine thanks.

Answer (score 13):

1. Please change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`,
2. To change directly from database Goto -> `core_config_data` table
3. Then change secure and unsecure base url

**http://localhost/ to http://127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 8):

Those who don't wish to change the localhost url for this problem.

The problem is due to form_key mismatch. The form key which gets posted during add to cart action is getting mismatched with store session form key.

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php execute()

method and comment out the below If condition.

```
if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```

**NOTE:** This is not a recommended solution for Production environment.

Reference:  [quick fix](http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2017/03/magento-2-cannot-add-products-to-cart.html).

Answer (score 2):

After my test, Magento 2 cannot work properly  in **single** domain name, like `http://localhost/`, `http://mysite/`, `http://localsite/` etc.

Other than use the **127.0.0.1** directly, we could change our site url like  `http://mysite/` to `http://mysite.local/`, and add `127.0.0.1 mysite.local` to our computer **host file**, then we could use the site function like "add to cart" properly.

Comment: Yes, that work with .local append at last, but how this work?

Comment: @Sourav The official codes don't consider using single domain name as site url, because it is impossible in production env.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my localhost. Basically what I did was change the base url from the admin area.

Go to store ->configuration ->web ->Base URL ->

change it to `http://127.0.0.1/your_magento_installation/`

it worked from me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be solved by changing domain url from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Can be changed in database in core_config_data

set  web/unsecure/base_url  to http://127.0.0.1

After this clear magento cache and browser cache and its works.