# Magento2 Product Edit Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page?

Tags: magento2.2

**Magento 2.2.2** Product Edit with More than 25 options on Custom Options gets error Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page? Can anyone help how to solve this issues?
[image]

Comment: We also face the same issue. Please let us know if you find any solutions for that.

Comment: Sure I'll let you know if I find any solution for that.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160829/magento2-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page try this

Answer (score 4):

Open your server's php.ini file with root user, search for `max_input_vars` and set its value as `100000` and it will solve your problem.

```
max_input_vars = 100000
```

Answer (score 3):

php.ini file variable `max_input_vars` increase it to 10000 through below php function

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 10000);
```

OR Using Linux command line

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/apache2/
vi php.ini (Open for edit and set max_input_vars=10000)
:wq(Press esc and write the mentioned command to save and exit)
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart(Restart Server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried that but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini set max_input_vars to 75000.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried that but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add: php_value max_input_vars 10000
to file .htaccess, I hope it can help someone!