# Invalid Form Key, Please refresh the page - could not login to magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I have implemented `Magento 1.9` and whenever I use varnish I am not able to login to the admin-panel. Since I have used `Redis` to stored session and cache, the folders related to these are empty. I have checked other similar post, but none of those worked.

Comment: follow link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160829/invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page

Comment: I believe I have checked all similar questions here, therefore I am asking. I do not think the answer is to change the value of max_input_vars. I think it has to do something with varnish setting or the form key

Comment: Yes it's session/cookie issue for that check with private window

Comment: If you disable Varnish and Redis, does it work?

Comment: If I disable varnish, it works