# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. magento 2.3.X

Tags: magento2, php, addtocart

When I clicked on add to cart or add product in **wishlist** then showing error as below:

[image]

How can I fix this issue ? Where is the form key to change or what can I do ?

Comment: follow this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160829/invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page.

Comment: Is it live or localhost ? @RK7002

Comment: it is localhost

Comment: i have updated my ans implement it now and let me know about the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your baseurl from `http://localhost/` to `http://127.0.0.1/`.

From **Admin** Panel :

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web

`Change  Base URLs` & `Secure Base URL (Secure)`

Using **command** line :

**Use SSH**

```
mysql -u $database_user -p $database_name
```

**Access the database**

```
use database

select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

**Update Base Url :**

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://example.com/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data set value = 'https://example.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Clean **cache**:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your env.php file and set the base url from `localhost to 127.0.0.1`
location for env.php file is `<magento root directory>app\etc`

and then go to you php.ini file and look for this line  `max_input_var=100000`
now just `flush:cache` and you are done

Comment: max_input_vars     search this and update the value

Comment: I have done changes as you suggest but still I'm facing same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with magento 2.3, where **Add to Cart** button refreshed the page instead of adding anything in cart. where as website was working properly in **Private Browsing** on a custom theme.

**Solutions Didn't Worked:**

- Change max_input_var=10000
- max_input_time = 600
- max_execution_time = 3600
- Flush cache

**Solution Worked for me:**

In Configuration >> Web, I:

- change **baseURL** from **http://www.domain.com** to **http://domain.com**
- change **Secure Base URL** from **https://www.domain.com** to **https://domain.com**
- Flush cache

I am not sure if its a reliable fix or a temporary, but it resolved the issue for now.