# Add to Cart is not working - Magento 2.2 - with Browser: Chrome v61.0

Tags: addtocart, magento2.2.0

I am having a problem with, **Add To Cart** on both **Listing page** and **Product page**.

When I am adding a product to the cart from listing page, it's showing the cart page with no products. (see the below screen grab).

[image]

While adding the product to the cart from the **Product page**, it's showing same page in Ajax response!

Working only in `Firefox`

This issue I found on the **local server** and using `localhost` instance in the browser

Comment: I think the problem is with the chrome browser, isn't it ?.
1) Are you having this problem in your local machine ?   
2)  Are you accessing the local instance by using http://localhost   or http://your local ip address ?

Comment: @MGento I have updated the question, please review it. Thanks!

Comment: This problem is also reported by others and the solution is to update the base url and secure base url in your admin. Please have a look in to the below post. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105042/add-to-cart-not-working-localhost-only-in-chrome-magento-2-fresh-install

Comment: Try your url localhost to 127.0.0.1 from core_config_data and clear cache.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Having the same problem but it isn't related to the url. Just started after upgrade to 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
change
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
From http://localhost/magento2community/
to http://127.0.0.1/magento2community/
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating to **Magento 2.2.3 from 2.2.0**.

Well, This is what worked for me.It was an issue with a Third Party Module.

Update all of your modules. If it still persists, then disable them one by one until you figure out which one is causing the issue. For me, it was one of my **Amasty Modules**.

Once I updated, all was good.