# Not able to submit form in chrome

Tags: magento2.3

I have installed fresh magento2 version.

The page keeps loading or the session expired ( error ).
And the customer can't log-in/ submit the form.

But this is working perfectly on Mozilla browser.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your magento2 on localhost ?

There is an issue with chrome cookies and localhost domains,
 if this is the case, refer to: [add to cart not working localhost Only in chrome (Magento 2 fresh install )](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105042/add-to-cart-not-working-localhost-only-in-chrome-magento-2-fresh-install)

Comment: I have tried " http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ "

but this redirects me to the localhost again.
I have followed these steps also

1)
UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/' 
WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');
2) flush the cache (bin/magento cache:flush).
3)  clear out your var directories with 
     rm -rf var/cache and var/page_cache

Comment: Anything else I can try?

Comment: dont forget to specify the protocol inside the base_urls. Means `https://127.0.0.1/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` . I just saw that stackechange does not show the protocol in links, so maybe you did this already

Comment: yes i have tried with the same given. still the same

Comment: How are you running the magento2 local instance ? You may also need to update your domain in the webserver configuration. At least there is an additional place, where it still uses localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks, this thing works.