# Magento2 - can't add product in cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I am not able to add product to cart.
[image]

tried these solutions but not working.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463643/magento-2-products-not-being-added-to-cart

[add to cart not working localhost Only in chrome (Magento 2 fresh install )](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105042/add-to-cart-not-working-localhost-only-in-chrome-magento-2-fresh-install)

can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please check in response tab what response you're getting there ? There may be some exceptions so you're getting 500 error there.

Comment: I am getting a blank response tab.

Comment: go to app/bootstrap.php file and uncomment init_set() error reporting line and then check

Comment: Check var/report folder. There are error report generated.

Comment: I reverted updates in 'core_config_data' table. now error is not coming ajax call getting 200 ok msg. but when I open any product (product detail page) like-http://localhost/magento/proteus-fitness-jackshirt.html it shows error like - 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on string in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php:318 Stack trace: #0'

Comment: @RohanHapani var/report having 4 files, which should latest, which I need to check

Comment: You can check from network response. There are report file number will be display.

Comment: @ Dimple Panchal
turn on error report from index.php file, Please add below code in index.php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Now check ajax response,

$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

Comment: Yes I have done and added the error is : Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data

Comment: ok problem resolved .. there was a custom module causing this issue.